# Empty streamplot: Cartopy and longitude coordinate range [0, 360]

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, cartopy

I'm trying to plot a streamplot over a map, using xarray and cartopy. However, the graphic is empty. I'm using wind components from NCEP Reanalysis 2, which file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTs64VZenEhqYhD9do6LRyJsGUhJBdXg/view?usp=sharing). This data has longitude coordinates ranging from 0 to 360 degrees, and longitude coordinates ranging from 90 to -90 degrees.

Plotting streamlines without a map works as expected (I had to sort data by increasing latitude, as expected by streamplot function):

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

dados = xr.open_dataset('u_v_sample_data.nc')
dados = dados.sortby('lat')

lc = dados.sel(time='2023-03-17-00',
               level=250,
               lat=slice(-60,10),
               lon=slice(270,330)).plot.streamplot(x='lon',
                                                   y='lat',
                                                   u='u',
                                                   v='v')

vetores = dados.sel(time='2023-03-17-00',
                     level=250,
                     lat=slice(-60,10),
                     lon=slice(270,330)).plot.quiver(x='lon',
                                                     y='lat',
                                                     u='u',
                                                     v='v')

plt.show()
```

This code creates the following plot:

[image: Streamlines without cartopy map]

When trying to plot same data over a map with cartopy, I'm getting a empty graphic (vector plot works fine, instead):

```
mapa = plt.axes( projection=ccrs.PlateCarree() )

lc = dados.sel(time='2023-03-17-00',
               level=250,
               lat=slice(-60,10),
               lon=slice(270,330)).plot.streamplot(x='lon',
                                                   y='lat',
                                                   u='u',
                                                   v='v',
                                                   transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                                                   density=5,
                                                  ax=mapa)

vetores = dados.sel(time='2023-03-17-00',
                     level=250,
                     lat=slice(-60,10),
                     lon=slice(270,330)).plot.quiver(x='lon',
                                                     y='lat',
                                                     u='u',
                                                     v='v',
                                                     transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                                                    ax=mapa)
mapa.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
mapa.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

Resulting the graphic below:

[image: Streamlines with cartopy map]

Finally, plotting streamlines with cartopy map only works if longitude coordinates are transformed to [-180,180] range, as shown below (note longitudes coordinates in the slice function):

```
dados.coords['lon'] = ( ( dados.coords['lon'] + 180 ) % 360 ) - 180
dados = dados.sortby( dados.lon )

mapa = plt.axes( projection=ccrs.PlateCarree() )

lc = dados.sel(time='2023-03-17-00',
               level=250,
               lat=slice(-60,10),
               lon=slice(-90,-30)).plot.streamplot(x='lon',
                                                   y='lat',
                                                   u='u',
                                                   v='v',
                                                   transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                                                   density=5,
                                                  ax=mapa)

vetores = dados.sel(time='2023-03-17-00',
                     level=250,
                     lat=slice(-60,10),
                     lon=slice(-90,-30)).plot.quiver(x='lon',
                                                     y='lat',
                                                     u='u',
                                                     v='v',
                                                     transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                                                    ax=mapa)
mapa.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
mapa.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

Resulting ...

[image: Streamlines with cartopy map]

In streamplot docs, there is only one requeriment to the arrays for x and y data: *Evenly spaced strictly increasing arrays to make a grid*, since they are 1D arrays.

It seems that streamplot function cannot place/draw correctly streamlines over a cartopy map when longitude data is in [0,360] range.

Is it an expected behaviour or is there a problem with streamplot and cartopy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your quote: `It seems that streamplot function cannot place/draw correctly streamlines over a cartopy map when longitude data is in [0,360] range...`,  you already know it.

I can confirm that with some coding and output plots below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

noproj = projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
shift90E = projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=90)
shift180 = projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)
shift90W = projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-90)

# Creating dataset
w = 180
h = 90
# Domains of X,Y: (-180, 180), (-90, 90)
# Domains of X,Y are chosen to comply with ability to plot
#  successfully with Cartopy.
Y, X = np.mgrid[-h:h:100j, -w:w:100j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
#speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 6])

def ax_plot(index, use_project, title):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,index, projection = use_project)
    ax.streamplot(X,Y,U,V, density=[0.8, 0.8],transform=noproj,linewidth=0.6,minlength=0.2,arrowstyle='->')
    ax.set_extent([-180,180, -90,90], crs=noproj)
    ax.coastlines(resolution='110m', alpha=0.3)
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=["bottom", "left"])
    ax.set_title(title)

ax_plot(1, noproj, "Zero-meridian-centered")
ax_plot(2, shift90E, "Centered at 90E longitude")
ax_plot(3, shift180, "Dateline-centered")
ax_plot(4, shift90W, "Centered at 90W longitude")
plt.show()
```

With the proper data in the longitude domain (-180, 180), all the plots on the projections with any longitude shifts are good.

[image: goodplots]

To compare with similar data set that has longitude domain (0, 360),
just after the line of code

```
V = 1 + X - Y**2
```

the code below is added

```
X += 180
```

and after running the code, I get these plots. Clearly one of these plots are not acceptable.

[image: badplots]